# Interpreting the output of kafka-producer-perf-test

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using the kafka-producer-perf-test utility to baseline the producer performance in our Kafka cluster. I am specifically interested in "records written/sec". I see the following lines in the output of the utility:

```
32561 records sent, 6407.1 records/sec (6.11 MB/sec), 1223.3 ms avg latency, 2399.0 ms max latency.
50000 records sent, 8123.476848 records/sec (7.75 MB/sec), 1628.84 ms avg latency, 2801.00 ms max latency, 1701 ms 50th, 2701 ms 95th, 2796 ms 99th, 2799 ms 99.9th
```

This seems to indicate that the throughput is 8123 records/sec

However in the sections that follow there is another metric:

```
producer-topic-metrics:record-send-rate:{client-id=producer-1, topic=test1}   : 1409.602
```

I am unable to reconcile the two figures. Which should be considered the throughput of the producer?

Comment: Do you have producer `batch-size` set explicitly in your tests? If not, could you set it to 1 and try again?

Comment: I haven't set the batch-size explicitly. As per the output of the utility, the values being used are: 

producer-metrics:batch-size-avg:{client-id=producer-1}                                  : 16190.179
producer-metrics:batch-size-max:{client-id=producer-1}                                  : 16220.000